Can I "receive a fee" as well as pay one?
I've often heard the word fee being used when someone is paying something, but I can't remember ever heard it used in the context of "receiving a fee". Can it be used in this way, just as I can say for example "received a payment"?
For example, would this sentence be correct?:

I'll receive part of the fee as soon as half of the job is done.


Yes: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/receive-a-fee

Why wouldn't it be possible to say that? Chances are that the question will be closed as too obvious for this site, unless you provide some reason for doubting the correctness of such locutions.

My fee will be $1000 please. I need to receive this fee before the consultation can proceed. When I have been paid the fee, I will provide a receipt.

Yes.
My source is that I can remember hearing it used in the context of receiving a fee. However, here's additional information: @dubious points out this source in his comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/receive-a-fee
